# combining jquery validate and ajaxForm plugins

Tags: jquery, plugins, validation, ajaxform

I had both the validation and the ajaxform working fine alone, but when I try to combine the form doesn't work properly. I am not that familiar with JQuery and so think the syntax is wrong somewhere. Can anyone spot what Im doing wrong?

The form takes two attempts before it validates, and then the form sends but does not give any response.

// prepare the form when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
target: '#output1', // target element(s) to be updated with server response
beforeSubmit: showRequest, // pre-submit callback
success: showResponse // post-submit callback
};

// bind form using 'ajaxForm'
$('form#webcheck').ajaxForm(options);
});

function showRequest(){
$("form#webcheck").validate();
jQuery.validator.messages.required = jQuery.validator.messages.email = "";
jQuery.validator.messages.required = jQuery.validator.messages.telephone = "";
jQuery.validator.messages.required = jQuery.validator.messages.name = "";
}

function showResponse(){
alert('Thanks for your comment!');
}

Comment: I have solved the above whereby the form now does give a response and it validates first time. However, now whats happening is the form is submitting whether the form is validated or not.  So the fields that need validating are comign up as red AND the form is submitting and giving the response.  The amended code is below.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        //target:        '#response',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
    }; 

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('form#webcheck').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 

function showRequest(){ 
    jQuery.validator.messages.required = jQuery.validator.messages.email = "";
    jQuery.validator.messages.required = jQuery.validator.messages.telephone = "";
    jQuery.validator.messages.required = jQuery.validator.messages.name = "";
    $("form#webcheck").validate().form();

}

function showResponse(){ 
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
}
```